# Empty the text box if data's are entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Data's entered in the popup text box gets cleared if cancel button is pressed.

I used the below code for performing this,

```
function clear()
{
 document.getElementById("spacevalidate").setTextValue() = "";
}
```

html is for popup box is

```
<div id="overlay_form" style="display:none">
       <h2> Create New Incident Type</h2>
        <br />
        Name
        <input type="text" id="spacevalidate" style="height:30px;" name="title" maxlength="30" /><br />
        <div style="width:180px;float:right;margin:20px 5px 0 10px">
            <button id="bsave" type="submit" name="save" title="Save" class="forward">Save</button>
            <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" id="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

update:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //open popup
        $("#addalist").click(function(){
            $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
            positionPopup();
        });
```

1.Now i enter some data and press cancel button,again i open the same popup,data's are avail in the text box.I want to clear that on every open if some data's entered and cancel button is pressed.

Comment: Do you have a function that opens your Modal (popup = 80's), you probably need to place the same document.getElementById there as well to.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
function clear()
{
   document.getElementById("spacevalidate").value = "";
}
```

Comment: No,still the same,I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

As Cam said, just call `clear()` in the function that opens the modal.

Comment: You must show us the function that opens the 'popup'. You will have something like `myFunctionThatOpensThePopup(){clear();/*rest of the function*/}`

Comment: Hi,i updated the function to open popup.I tried apply that but no popup is opening

Comment: You mean, since you have added the `clear()` call to your function, the popup isn't showing anymore ? Use the debug tool of your browser to check for mistakes and errors